# WP Editor strips input placeholder attribute

Tags: wp-editor, html-editor, wp-kses

Why WP Editor also strips the "placeholder" attribute of the input text element ?
Ofcourse, i am using the HTML mode.
Here is the input:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="s" style="width: 550px;" placeholder="Search this website..">
```

After updating the post (after strip):

```
<input type="text" value="" name="s" style="width: 550px;">
```

I do not want WP Editor to strip such attributes.

Any Help ?

Answer (score 3):

The list of allowed elements and attributes is stored in the global variable `$allowedposttags` which is set in `wp-includes/kses.php`.

To override it create a simple [mu plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) with the following content:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: Enable placeholder attribute for input elements in post tags.
 * Version: 2012.07.18
 */

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_54829_register_placeholder' );


function wpse_54829_register_placeholder()
{
    global $allowedposttags;

    $default = empty ( $allowedposttags['input'] ) ? array () : $allowedposttags['input'];
    $custom  = array (
        'placeholder' => TRUE,
        'name'        => TRUE,
        'value'       => TRUE,
        'size'        => TRUE,
        'maxlength'   => TRUE,
        'type'        => TRUE,
        'required'    => TRUE
    );

    $allowedposttags['input'] = array_merge( $default, $custom );
}
```

This post with the content `<input placeholder="pass" required />`  was created with an author account:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shortcode! ;)

```
<?php

// desired output: <input type="text" value="" name="s" style="width: 550px;" placeholder="Search this website..">
// sc: [text_input name="s" style="width: 550px;" placeholder="Search this website.."]

add_shortcode('text_input','text_input_sc');
function text_input_sc($atts) {

    // modify defaults as you wish
    $defaults = array(
        'id' => null,
        'class' => null,
        'value' => null,
        'name' => null,
        'size' => null,
        'style' => null,
        'placeholder' => null
    );

    $args = shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts);

    $out = array();

    foreach ($args as $attr => $value) {

        if ( null !== $value )
            $out[] = $attr.'="'.$value.'"';

    }

    $out = trim(implode(' ', $out));

    if( !empty($out) )
        $out = ' '.$out;

    return vsprintf('<input type="text"%s>', $out);

}
```

Untested, but should definitely work!